# Gingerbread power management for services

Tags: android, android-service, android-sdk-2.3

According to http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3-highlights.html there are now circumstances other than low system memory that can result in background services being killed:

> The Android system takes a more active role in managing apps that are keeping the device awake for too long or that are consuming CPU while running in the background. By managing such apps — closing them if appropriate — the system helps ensure best possible performance and maximum battery life.

Is there a list of the circumstances under which such a process killing can occur? Is there a way to detect this circumstance and handle it gracefully?

Finally, does making a service a foreground service help in this case?